# Reaching proportional correspondents in a interval

Tags: r, distance, intervals

I would like to obtain proportional correspondent in a  numerical interval to a new column `pos` to my `df`:

```
df <- "SNP CHR BP P
       pr1  1  1  1
       pr2  1  10 1 
       pr3  1  11 1
       pr6  2  1  1
       pr7  2  2  1
       pr8  2  3  1
       pr8  2  9  1"
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

In `df` I am trying to get the correspondent to the `BP` column. The `BP` column go from `1` (`CHR 1`) to `9` (`CHR 2`). Considering the total `BP` interval  in `df` as continuous we get: from `1` to `20`. I previous know the limits to be compared, which is `from` `-20` `to` `20`. Thus we have `20` (interval in `df` `BP`) to be compared with `40` (interval to be compared). However from one row to another we have different "distances".

This is what I expect as output `dfout`:

```
dfout <- "SNP CHR BP  P  pos
           pr1  1  1  1  -20
           pr2  1  10 1   0
           pr3  1  11 1   2
           pr6  2  1  1   4 
           pr7  2  2  1   6
           pr8  2  3  1   8
           pr8  2  9  1  20"
    dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

You can understand my data as one manhattan plot. Each chromosome (`CHR`) have specific `SNPs`to be plotted. Each `CHR` will be subsequentially plotted. Then in a `x-axis` we will get a unique interval (the `y-axis` would be `P` but is unnecessary to access this problem). I previous know this `x-axis`interval (`from -20 to 20`). Then I would like to assign the proportional number of `x-axis` based on `CHR` and `BP`.

Am am searching for some trick like:

```
df$pos <- seq(from = -20, to = 20, length.out = nrow(df))
```

The problem with my usage in `seq` is that each "`SNP`" will be assigned with a correspondent number which ignores orignal interval between probes (example: the distance between `pr1` and `pr2` is quite different comparing with `pr6` and `pr7`).

This code `((((df[2,3] - df[1,3]))+1)*2)-(((df[2,3]-df[1,3])+1)*2)` would be enough to reach expected value in `dfout[2,5]` for example. We multiplied by 2 because `pos` have the interval two times larger than value in `BP` (Total interval in `BP` == `20`, Total interval in `pos` == `40`).

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you try to achieve? I am lost, your explanation is fully opaque ... for example how do you obtain the `pos` on second row? on the third row?

Comment: Also, `BP` have values higher than `9`

Comment: "considering the total `BP` interval in `df` as continuous we get `20`", can you reformulate this as well?

Comment: Please check my additional explanation and if it is not enough, feel free to ask more inf.

Comment: Can you provide the formula of how the first 3 values of `pos` were calculate, for example?

Comment: What is the logic for getting to the values in the `pos`-column? The code `((((df[2,3] - df[1,3]))+1)*2)-(((df[2,3]-df[1,3])+1)*2)` will always lead to `0`, which is not your desired output. So, please clarify.